# Tomar solo un registro en base a una columna en consulta. DB2

Tags: java, db2

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT
    a.datoA AS datoUno,
    a.datoB AS datoDos,
    a.datoC as datoTres,
    sv.fecha AS fechaUno,

FROM
    tableUno a
 INNER JOIN tableDos sv ON
    sv.datoId = a.datoId

WHERE
    a.STATUS = 1
GROUP BY
    a.datoA,
    a.datoB,
    a.datoC,
    sv.fecha 
ORDER BY
    to_number(a.datoA) WITH ur
```

Me arroja:

```
datoUno     | datoDos          |datoTres|  fechaUno
------------|------------------|------- |--------------------------
4           |1177525           |       2|2017-05-06-13.50.00.000000
4           |1177525           |       2|2017-05-08-05.48.00.000000
4           |1177525           |       2|2017-05-08-14.45.00.000000
5           |1177526           |       2|2017-05-08-14.45.00.000000
```

Lo que quiero es que no me repita los datos, es decir que solo me muestre un registro por DatoUno, en este caso me muestra más de uno por las fechas, quiero que solo tome la fecha más reciente.

Es decir:

```
datoUno     | datoDos          |datoTres|  fechaUno
------------|------------------|------- |--------------------------
4           |1177525           |       2|2017-05-08-14.45.00.000000
5           |1177526           |       2|2017-05-08-14.45.00.000000
```

Intenté con un DISTINCT en datoUno pero no me funcionó. Las fechas se que debo hacer un order by pero no se como podría meterlo.

Si pudieran ayudarme.

Comment: Pero estas agrupando por fecha y las fechas son distintas por eso te muestra mas registros...no es que esté repitiendo

Comment: Gracias por responde, tal vez no me explique adecuadamente. Lo que quiero es que solo se muestre un registro en base a datoUno, comprendo que se repiten porque las fechas son distintas, pero quisiera que de estas solo tome la más reciente y asi no tener 3 registros para datoUno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías tomar una decisión de utilizar las columnas 2, 3 y 4 con un `MAX` o `MIN` y agrupar solo por la columna 1.

```html
SELECT
    a.datoA AS datoUno,
    MAX(a.datoB AS datoDos),
    MAX(a.datoC as datoTres),
    MAX(sv.fecha AS fechaUno)

FROM
    tableUno a
 INNER JOIN tableDos sv ON
    sv.datoId = a.datoId

WHERE
    a.STATUS = 1
GROUP BY
    a.datoA
 ORDER BY
    to_number(a.datoA) WITH ur
```

Aparte fijate que antes del `FROM` te sobra una `,`

Comment: Siguiendo tu sugerencia me funciona, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
SELECT
    a.datoA AS datoUno,
    a.datoB AS datoDos,
    a.datoC as datoTres,
    sv.fecha AS fechaUno
FROM
    tableUno a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT datoId, max(fecha) 
    FROM tableDos 
    GROUP BY datoID) sv
ON
    sv.datoId = a.datoId
WHERE
    a.STATUS = 1
```